# Not able to apply three filters in one SQL query

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have created a Report.aspx page where 3 filters are applied for fetching table from database, the filters are Firstname, City, Languages. But if FirstName and City is null and only Language is selected from Dropdown, no records are showing. And Firstname and City is working fine. Could anyone tell me what is the issue here!! Why Languages filter is not working?

SQL query from stored procedure:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    T1.EmpId, T1.FirstName, T1.LastName, T1.Contact, 
    T1.Gender, T1.City, T1.Username, T1.Password, 
    T1.ConfirmPassword, T1.Gmail, 
    T2.Languages 
FROM 
    Employeedata AS T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT EmpId, string_agg(Languages, ' , ') AS Languages 
     FROM EmployeeLanguages 
     GROUP BY EmpId) T2 ON T1.EmpId = T2.EmpId 
WHERE
    (T1.FirstName = @FirstName)
    OR (T1.City = @City) 
    OR (T2.Languages = @Languages)
```

Search button code from Report.aspx.cs page:

```
 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            int EmpId = hfEmpId.Value == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(hfEmpId.Value);
            String FirstName = txtFirstName.Text.Trim();
            String City = txtCity.Text.Trim();
            String Languages = Convert.ToString(DropDownList1.SelectedValue); 
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("EmployeeSearchByID", con);
            sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId",EmpId);
            sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName",FirstName);
            sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", City );
            sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Languages", Languages);
            
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
            con.Close();
            Gridview1.DataSource = dtbl;
            Gridview1.DataBind();
            Gridview1.Visible = true;
        }
```

Languages dropdownlist code from Report.aspx page:

```
<td>Languages</td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" >
                          <asp:ListItem Text="Select Languages" Value="select" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Asp.Net" Value="Asp.Net" ></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="C#" Value="C#" ></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Text="JQuery" Value="JQuery" ></asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem Text="JavaScript" Value="JavaScript" ></asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem Text="SQL Server" Value="SQL Server" ></asp:ListItem>
                         </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
```

Comment: Try `( T1.FirstName = @FirstName OR @FirstName IS NULL)` etc.

Comment: You are applying your language filter to the T2 table, which is left joined. This effectively changes the left join to behave like an inner join.

Comment: As implied by @jarlh, `(T1.FirstName = @Firstname)` will ALWAYS be false if either `T1.FirstName IS NULL` or `@FirstName IS NULL`. So your query filter should consider whether either the table row might have NULL in it, or if the user may not have selected a value and therefore the SQL procedure paramter might have NULL in it.